# Copy entire column (flexible size) to another file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function CopyRange() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'); 
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Weight'); 
 var range = ss.getRange('U2:U'); 
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Registros');

 ts.getRange(2, 1).setValues(data);

}
```

I am not able to adjust the script so that the data size of the column to be copied is flexible, as the initial spreadsheet data grows over time.

I would like to know if there is any way to make the getRange of the spreadsheet that will receive the data adjust according to the range size of the complete column to be copied (Like Column A2:A).

Example:

The Column (U2:U) to be copied currently has 1800 rows, then the spreadsheet's getRange that will receive the values (A2:A) needs to be 1800 rows, when it grows, which automatically increases as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
// if there aren't enough rows, insert some
if(ts.getMaxRows() <= data.length) ts.insertRows(2, data.length);

// find a range of the same size as the source data, then set the values
ts.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

Comment: That's perfect mate! Thanks.